# Jumping between different 'layers' in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I've ran into a small problem with navigation controllers. I've set up a navigation controller with 2 'branches'.
Like aviewController1>aViewController2>aviewController3, and the other branch is biewController1>bviewController2. Now what I would like to do is to have an option to go from the current position to the bottom (first view) of the other branch (e.g aviewController3>bviewController1 etc). Obviously a simple `[self.navigationController addSubview:someview.view]`won't do the job as it will only get me to that view and will still retain the current stack count of the nav controller. Could I get some ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pop multiple stacks by just calling pop multiple times. If you make all the popViewController:animated: calls with animated set to NO, it should be seamless.

Alternatively, navigation controller has a setViewControllers:animated: method that lets you swap the whole stack out for a different set of view controllers. Using that you can copy the existing view controller stack into a mutable array, remove the ones you don't want, append the ones you do, and then replace the old stack with your new stack in one go.

Comment: I've tried calling [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; multiple times after each other but only the first stack get's poped. This is how you meant it right?

Comment: Are you calling that from within one of the view controllers? If so it won't work more than once because once you've popped the view controller you're currently calling from, the self.navigationController will be nil because that viewController is no longer in the navigation stack. You need to get a reference to the navigationController and store it in a variable, then you can pop it multiple times. e.g. UINavigationController *controller = self.navigationController; [controller popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; [controller popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; etc...

Answer (score 1):

Since the navigation controller is basically a stack, the safe way to do it is to simply pop a3, pop a2, pop a1 and then push b1.

if the branch is your root controller then you can speed it up by doing a popto Root controller

Comment: A silly question, but how do I pop multiple stacks at the same time?

Comment: Unless you are going down to the root controller, I would just pop them off one at a time.

Comment: I won't need to go down to the root controller so this should work. But somehow when I call pop multiple times it only seems to pop 1 stack. I'm calling this from an UIActionSheet button press, can that cause problems?

Comment: Where are you calling your popping code from? Is it from within one of the view controllers that is being popped?

Comment: Yes, you may need to call your Delegate and do the pops from there.  Possibly Nick's solution will work better in this case, using the setViewControllers -- I wasn't aware of that option.

Comment: Yes I'm calling this from the current view controller.

Comment: Ah yes, managed to solve it. Had to call the pop's through my root view controller and it works fine so far .)